# Which file should my style be in

Tags: theming

I'm putting this question in the Drupal forum rather than a CSS forum as I don't know if I just have a CSS issue or if the issue is more Drupal, maybe how I'm using the .info file.

I'm using Drupal 7 with UberCart and the AT Commerce sub-theme of Adaptivethemes.
If I put my CSS in styles.base.css they take effect. However, it I put my CSS in a separate CSS then they do not.

I edited at_commerce.info so I have this

```
// CSS
stylesheets[all][] = css/styles.custom.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/styles.base.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/styles.modules.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/styles.settings.css
stylesheets[all][] = color/colors.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/uc_product.css
```

I tried styles.custom.css as the first in the list as shown above and the last in the list and it make no difference. styles.custom.css is empty except for the 2 styles I'm trying to put there. When I put the 2 styles in styles.base.css I am putting them at the bottom of the file.

Comment: I failed to say clearly that the 'separate css file' is styles.custom.css. The styles don't work when I put them in this file.

Comment: Your css should work. Maybe your other css has the same style, which overwrite?

Comment: Thanks CocoSkin. Looking at firebug I don't see that. However, requirements change, as did the requirement that needed this style such that I no longer need to introduce the new style so going to stop looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just to eliminate a possible cause of your problem: **if** you have enabled CSS aggregation **then** you must clear the cache before changes to CSS files become active.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Pierre. I've done that and it is not the problem.